# Bug: Ad / ad container has fixed (smaller) width

Tags: bug

The ads are looking a little wonky today:

[image]

Seems like the image has a fixed width:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDqLU.png" alt="Chat with fellow site members" title="Chat with fellow site members" width="220" height="250">
```

Comment: Oddly, this is a 2015 ad. None of our [2016 ads](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/2881/8708) have crossed the 6 point threshold. Perhaps that's related? Our site is stuck in 2015

Comment: @JohnB That's not too bad. I'm stuck in 1994. Great year!

Comment: @Yisela I'm not born in your world then :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wider sidebar rollout has had some [bumps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273255/216955) and [snags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273089/216955). As a result, the 2016 commmunity promotion ads aren't live yet.

> I've been holding off on the official activation of the new threads
> since people haven't had much time to design new ads to accommodate
> the new width (and also to look into some changes on the new filesize
> limits). This, though, slightly undermines that so let's see if we can
> do something about that. – Grace Note♦ [Jan 18 at 15:31](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273255/please-dont-stretch-the-old-community-ads#comment888053_273255)

> I'm thinking [2016 ads will be activated] mid or late February at the
> moment. It'll depend a lot on how much new submissions we get. – Grace
> Note♦ [Jan 18 at 15:35](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273255/please-dont-stretch-the-old-community-ads#comment888056_273255)